# Which C/C++ GUI toolkit does support Office 2003/2007 styles

Tags: windows, user-interface, mfc, ms-office, toolkit

I don't need ribbons but I would like to have the blue/orange style.

Currently I planned to use WxWidgets but it seems to be not able to do anything like this.

Do I have an alternative other then MFC + Featurepack ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes -- MFC + SP1 (which replaces the feature pack), and/or VS 2010 (which includes feature pack-like capabilities in the base package.

If mean to ask whether there's a viable alternative to MFC (in general), then the answer is no, at least AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Feature pack is built over some [BCGSoft](http://www.bcgsoft.com/)'s control. You might want to have a look to their products.

Answer (score 0):

Codejock software has a nice MFC extension library that supports various Themes.  You can download their toolkit for evaluation and play with some of their samples that implement Themes. http://www.codejock.com